# How to make a WYSIHTML5 textarea required

Tags: html, wysihtml5

I was using an ordinary textarea and it was required:

`<textarea class="form-control textarea text-area-wysihtml5" id="information" placeholder="Informação" name="information" required></textarea>`

but now I want to use a text editor (WYSIHTML5).

Anyone know how to make it required?

```
 $(".textarea").wysihtml5();
```

Comment: you should try to figure out from the documentation how pass attributes to a DOM. However it  seems that this technology  is not supported anymore and the developments are inactives since almost two years(see [github repo](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5)

Comment: @mabe02 yeah, you're right, I solved the problem changing the validator I was using, but if you know any nice text editor that's I can use and make it required some how :D